# python - syntax suggestion - simulation

Tags: python, syntax, poisson

Consider the following code simulation a non-homogenous poisson process. The focus is on the Non_hom_poisson(T,n,N) function.

```
def lam_t(T): #calculates lam(t) at given t
    Lambda=[]
    t=T
    for i in range(len(T)):    
        Lambda.append(0.8+0.4*np.sin(0.2*np.pi*t[i]))
    return Lambda

def thinning(max_min,Lam_t,lam_min,times,subset_length): 
#thins max-min to lam(t)-lam_min
    t=0
    J=0
    I=0
    S=[]
    path=2
    t_J=np.arange(0,602,2)
    while (J<300):
        if (path==2):
            unif=np.random.uniform(0,1)
            X=(-1/float(max_min[J]))*np.log(unif)
            path=3
        if (path==3):
            if ((t+X)>t_J[J+1]):
                if ((J+2)>=300):
                    return S;
                X=(X-t_J[J+1]+t)*max_min[J+1]/float(max_min[J+2])
                t=t_J[J+1]
                J+=1
                path=3
            else:
                t+=(X)
                U=np.random.uniform(0,1)
                L_t=0.8+0.4*np.sin(0.2*(np.pi)*t)
                top_prob=float(L_t-lam_min[J])
                bottom_prob=float(max_min[J])
                prob=top_prob/float(bottom_prob)
                if (U<=(prob)):
                    I+=1
                    S.append(float(t))
                    path=2
        if (t>600):
            break
    return S;

def mod_lam(t,lam): 
    interval=float(np.mod(t,10))
    J=np.arange(2,12,2)
    for i in range(len(J)):
        if (interval<J[i]):
            return float(lam[i])
    return float(lam[i])

def Non_hom_poisson(T,n,N):
    time=np.arange(0.1,10.1,0.1)
    Lambda_t=lam_t(time)
    max_lam=[max(Lambda_t[x:(x+19)]) for x in range(0,len(time),20)]
    min_lam=[min(Lambda_t[x:(x+19)]) for x in range(0,len(time),20)]
    max_min_lam=[(max_lam[x]-min_lam[x]) for x in range(len(max_lam))]
    max_min_lam=np.tile(max_min_lam,60)
    min_lam=np.tile(min_lam,60)
    poisson_min=[np.random.poisson(float(min_lam[0]))]
    i=0
    while (poisson_min[i]<600):
        y=float(mod_lam(poisson_min[i],min_lam))
        x=-1/float(y)*np.log(np.random.uniform(0,1))
        poisson_min.append(float(x)+float(poisson_min[i]))
        i+=1
    thinned=thinning(max_min_lam,Lambda_t,min_lam,time,20)
    superposition=np.append(thinned,poisson_min)
    return np.sort(superposition)
NH=Non_hom_poisson(600,5,1)
print(NH)
```

I'm getting the following error - "'int' object is not callable" - when max_lam=[max(Lambda_t[x:(x+19)]) for x in range(0,len(time),20)] is called. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your code works for me.  Try restarting your kernel?

Comment: Confirmed working here too [Python 2.7].

Answer (score 3):

There are three function calls in that line: `range()`, `max()` and `len()`. Those are python builtins.

But neither of those identifiers are reserved words. So what's probably happened is that you have used one of those identifiers as a variable name in the global scope. Since both `len()` and `range()` are called with no error in the `lam_t()` function, it must be `max` that is an integer.

Which means that an assignment like this has been executed in the global scope.

```
max = 100
```

The code included in the question does not contain any such assignment, but the error message indicates that `max` points to an integer. You can reproduce the error in the python repl.

```
>>> max = 1
>>> max(1, 3, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> del max  # fix it
>>> max(1, 3, 2)
3
```

It's good practice to avoid using `sum`, `len`, `list`, `max`, `min`, `int`, `hash`, `dir` etc. as variable names.

It's a rich cause of confusing bugs if you are using something like a jupyter notebook where it's common practice to define lots of variables in the global namespace and then forget about it.